# Constant value defined in header creates unexpected behaviour with math operation

Tags: c, variables, math, c-preprocessor

Header "main.h" defines the following variables:

```
#define FRAMERATE 60.0f
#define RES_WIDTH 1920.0f
#define RES_HEIGHT 1080.0f
#define RATIO_X 16.0f
#define RATIO_Y 9.0f
#define INCH 27.0f
#define HEIGHT sqrt( pow(INCH,2.0f) / (pow((RATIO_X/RATIO_Y),2.0f) + 1.0f) ) * 2.54f
#define WIDTH (RATIO_X * HEIGHT) / RATIO_Y
#define PPCM RES_WIDTH / WIDTH
#define SEC 60.0f
```

Test-Code for Problem visualisation:

```
float speed = 1.0f;          // Pixle / Frame

printf("SEC: %f\n", SEC);    // Frames per Second
printf("PPCM: %f\n", PPCM);  // Pixle per centimeter

printf("1. Speed (CM/SEC): %f\n", (speed * SEC) / PPCM );   // speed in cm/second
printf("2. Speed (CM/SEC): %f\n", (speed * 60.0f) / PPCM );
printf("3. Speed (CM/SEC): %f\n", (speed * SEC) / 32.121715f );
printf("4. Speed (CM/SEC): %f\n", (speed * 60.0f) / 32.121715f );
```

Generates the following **OUTPUT**:

*SEC: 60.000000*

*PPCM: 32.121715*

*1. Speed (CM/SEC): 0.00523*

*2. Speed (CM/SEC): 0.00523*

*3. Speed (CM/SEC): 1.867895*

*4. Speed (CM/SEC): 1.867895*

Q: **Why can't I do correct math with the PPCM variable?** (1. and 2. solution is wrong)

Comment: PPCM's value is 32.121715. But the division by PPCM generates a wrong solution

Comment: When #defining macros that contain mathematical expressions, always enclose the arguments and the entire expression in parentheses to avoid unexpected results due to operator precedence.

Comment: Not related to your question, but consider removing the `f`; then you will get `double` precision at no cost, since these computations will happen at compile-time.

Comment: Also consider replacing `pow(X, 2.0f)` with `((X) * (X))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(speed * SEC) / PPCM` will equal `(speed * SEC) / RES_WIDTH / WIDTH`.

Always put parenthesis around macros:

```
#define HEIGHT (sqrt( pow(INCH,2.0f) / (pow((RATIO_X/RATIO_Y),2.0f) + 1.0f) ) * 2.54f)
#define WIDTH ((RATIO_X * HEIGHT) / RATIO_Y)    
#define PPCM (RES_WIDTH / WIDTH)
```